# Performance comparison of @FindBy() and driver.findElement()

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium framework to automate a web application wherein basically, driver.findElement() is commonly used. but I got the suggestion that @FindBy() works faster than driver.findElement(). suggest me which is better to use ?

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the code - `PageFactory.initElements(....)` is run it creates [Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) objects for all the fields which are annotated with @FindBy (or even @FindBys and @FindAll). So initially no searching of `WebElements` are performed.

Then if something like `element.sendKeys(...)` is run, the actual WebElement is searched using `driver.findElement(...)` before `sendKeys()` is run. Then if the same `sendKeys()` code is run the element is found again.

But if you add the `CacheLookup` annotation to the field then the second lookup is not performed but element is returned from the cache. So there is a performance gain. But the problem occurs in a javascript or ajax heavy page, stale element exception can show up.

For any non-trivial application testing use the `PageObjectModel` framework. Makes things organized and not littered with findElements and locators, even if you do not use the `CacheLookUp` annotation.

Comment: @Jilly  pls accept the answer so that it can be closed. `@FindBy` is just an alternate way of finding elements but with the additional annotation like `@CacheLookup` makes the lookup for the element happen just once which improves the performance.